# Why I can't add this "custom control" in a .ascx?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls

My .ascx is into folder /cms/context/ , and it is called Test.ascx (on .NET 4.0, WebForms).

When I try to add :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="iz" Namespace="IZ.WebFileManager" Assembly="IZ.WebFileManager" %>

<div>
    <iz:FileManager ID="FileManager1" runat="server" Height="400" Width="600">
        <RootDirectories>
            <iz:RootDirectory DirectoryPath="~/images/" Text="My Documents" />
        </RootDirectories>
    </iz:FileManager>    
</div>
```

I get :

> System.NullReferenceException. An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Why? And how can I fix it? Thanks

P.S. if I put the same code on Master Page it works as well...

Stack Trace :

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      IZ.WebFileManager.FileView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +167
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +112
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +221
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4200

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/izwebfilemanager/downloads/detail?name=IZWebFileManager_2_7_0_Bin_Demo.zip&can=2&q=) is the link where you can get that plugins. I just put the DLL into Bin folder and write that code into my Web User Control. Always used on Master Page, but in a WUC I have that trouble...

Comment: You can find it on my question :)

Comment: Thanks for adding that. "object reference not set to an instance of an object" is the translation for those who need it

Comment: sorry, didn't notice the italian language! Any idea?

Comment: also added the soruce and what I've done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only specify namespace and assembly you will only get the ascx.cs part of the control and not the code-front file (.ascx)
Since your code-behind file (.ascx.cs) is dependent on your code-front file (.ascx) to actually instantiate all the stuff you have declared, you need to include the Src in the register directive

```
<%@ Register Src="~/cms/context/Test.ascx" TagPrefix="iz" TagName="Test" %>
```

If you create your controls without a code-front file (what used to be called a "custom control") you can get by with only specifying namespace and assembly, but if you want to have the convenience of a code-front file ("user control") you need to specify the source.

All the built-in controls within the asp.net framework are created as Custom Controls which means that it was harder for Microsoft to write them (they couldn't use ascx files) but it's easier for us to consume them (single register line in web.config enables for all pages)

Comment: @Jakub that is true, but OP apparently misread your answer since he then went on: "...it works as well... I have other code that run..." I just thought I'd provide more context, I didn't mean to rain on your parade

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you are missing the source reference:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/cms/context/Test.ascx" TagPrefix="iz" TagName="Test" %>
```

Comment: you mean when I import the ascx in the .aspx? No, it works as well... I have other code that run...